# can't change grid's ui when reload data in grid into zkoss

Tags: mvvm, zk, zk-grid

i have a datebox

```
<datebox id="infrom" style ="z-index: 100000;" format="yyyy-MM-dd" value ="@bind(vm.date)"
    onChange="@global-command('dataChanged', indate = infrom.value)" />
```

default value of date is now -1
and have a button search

```
<button id="searchButton" label="Search" image="/img/search.png"  onClick="@command('listCars', indate = infrom.value)"/>
```

and grid will load data of yesterday
when i choose another day 
grid will load data of chose day
and there is my grid

```
<listbox id="carListbox" height="" emptyMessage="No data found in the result" model="@bind(vm.cars)" >

    <listhead>
        <listheader label="Date" />
        <listheader label="Actionid" />
        <listheader label="Num user" />
        <listheader label="Total action" />
    </listhead>
    <template name="model" >
        <listitem>
            <listcell label="@bind(each.date)"></listcell>
            <listcell label ="@bind(each.action)"></listcell>
            <listcell label="@bind(each.user)"></listcell>
            <listcell label="@bind(each.total)"></listcell>
        </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
```

and there are my code

```
private List<Car> cars;
public List<Car> getCars()
{

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date()); // Now use today date.
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
    String output = sdf.format(c.getTime());
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
    for (final Action action : getActions()) {
        if (action.getChecked()) {
          builder.append(';');
            builder.append(action.getActionid());
        }
    }
    String lstAction = builder.toString(); 
    lstAction = lstAction.substring(1);
    String[] arrAction = lstAction.split(";");
    cars = carService.search(output, arrAction);

    return cars;
}

    @Command
@NotifyChange("cars")
public void listCars(@BindingParam("indate") Date indate){
SimpleDateFormat dt1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date  = dt1.format(indate);
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("");
for (final Action action : actions) {
    if (action.getChecked()) {
      builder.append(';');
        builder.append(action.getActionid());
    }
}
String lstAction = builder.toString(); 
lstAction = lstAction.substring(1);
String[] arrAction = lstAction.split(";");
cars = carService.search(date, arrAction);
//return result;
//carListbox.setModel(new ListModelList<Car>(result));
}
```

but i can't reload grid when i choose another day
please give me any way to slove them
thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Why do you bind param to function with @BindingParam("indate")?

If you bind date value with this:

```
<datebox style ="z-index: 100000;" format="yyyy-MM-dd" value ="@bind(vm.date)"
onChange="@global-command('dataChanged', indate = infrom.value)" />
```

so you may not use

```
String date  = dt1.format(indate);
```

in listCars function, and not use @BindingParam in it.

Instead, you need to declare

```
private Date date;
```

in the viewmodel, with his getter and setter.

Comment: thanks you for help. but i found my mistake and and sloved them. i noted your ideal